# node.js | loopback, handling direct file upload

Tags: node.js, file, file-transfer, loopbackjs

is it possible for the client to directly push a file onto our servers via API?  How about pushing a file from our server to another again via API?

Right now my servers go out and grab files from locations via 'get'. This isn't the most efficient potentiality and there are reasons to believe I won't be able to access all files directly via get.

Comment: Yes. Possible with a lot of packages, and protocols. For instance http.

Comment: @bolav care to give an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For sending you can use the `request` module's [form feature](https://github.com/request/request#forms) to upload files.

```
var formData = {
  my_file: fs.createReadStream(__dirname + '/unicycle.jpg'),
};
request.post({url:'http://service.com/upload', formData: formData}, function optionalCallback(err, httpResponse, body) {
  if (err) {
    return console.error('upload failed:', err);
  }
  console.log('Upload successful!  Server responded with:', body);
});
```

For receiving files in node you can use something like express with [multer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer):

```
var multer  = require('multer')
var upload = multer({ dest: 'uploads/' })
app.post('/profile', upload.single('avatar'), function (req, res, next) {
  // req.file is the `avatar` file 
  // req.body will hold the text fields, if there were any 
})
```

Comment: Is it possible to do something similar without the need for a front / form infrastructure?  Directly via API.

Comment: You don't need a form to be able to post a form via the request package.

Comment: so the user will have to have formulate a radically different API call in order to make this request as opposed to a normal one without file transfer?  If so then so be it.  Is there a limit to a filesize with this method?  I'm talking mb or gb

Comment: How is the current API call? The method in itself does not have a limit in filesize, but the frameworks and methods to use it might.

Comment: right now they're sending us an address that is pointing to an open directory and we're sucking down the files via request.get()